# How to take a backup of a text file before modifying in c#?

Tags: c#

How do I make a backup copy of a text file (could be of extension *.txt, *.xml, *.html anything) before I modify it as a safety measure?
I tried

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\MyFolder\test.txt");
string path=@"D:\MyFolder\test.bk";
File.Create(path);
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
tw.WriteLine(xml);
tw.Close();
//code for modification of the original file i.e. "D:\MyFolder\test.txt"
File.WriteAllText(@"D:\MyFolder\test.txt", filecontentAsaString_after_modification);
```

But getting an exception **System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\MyFolder\test.bk' because it is being used by another process.**.
It should be easy...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use [`File.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_File_Copy_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use `Copy` like:

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\MyFolder\test.txt");
string path = @"D:\MyFolder\test.bk";
File.Copy(@"D:\MyFolder\test.txt", path); 
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
tw.WriteLine(xml);
tw.Close(); 
File.WriteAllText(@"D:\MyFolder\test.txt",filecontentAsaString_after_modification );
```

if the above code run twice you will get the exception as

> The file 'D:\MyFolder\test.bk' already exists.

to avoid that pass thrid parameter to Copy to replace it like:

```
File.Copy(@"D:\MyFolder\test.txt", path,true);
```